# What exactly is meant by linearity of a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I understand that formula for proving that it is linear, however, I don't understand what makes the transformation itself linear. This example from my notes has completely confused me. How do I even interpret this?
[image]

The column vector in $F$, can I split it like $x+y$ and then transform it?

Comment: No, one can't do this for the $F$ in the counterexample, because it is *not* linear.

Comment: yes but to prove that it isnt linear,how would I do that in this example?

Comment: Following the hint, if $F$ were linear, we'd have $F(\pmatrix{2\\0}) = F(2\pmatrix{1\\0}) = 2 F(\pmatrix{1\\0}) = 2 \pmatrix{(1)^2\\2(0)} = \pmatrix{2\\0}$, but using the formula for $F$ gives $F(\pmatrix{2\\0}) = \pmatrix{4\\0}$. These do not agree, so $F$ is not linear.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually understand it from this.! Yeah it makes sense when you look at it like that.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful!

Comment: @Travis Can you please transform your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Workaholic Sure, I've just done so.

Answer (score 2):

Following the hint: Computing using the definition of $F$ gives
$$
F(\pmatrix{a\\0}) = \pmatrix{a^2\\0} .
$$
On the other hand, if $F$ were linear, we'd have for all $a \in \Bbb R$ that
$$
F(\pmatrix{a\\0}) = a F(\pmatrix{1\\0}) = a \pmatrix{1\\0} = \pmatrix{a\\0} ,
$$
and this does not agree with the above computation (for all $a$), so $F$ is not linear.